# Grails 2.3.0 cannot access session in the view if session is not accessed before

Tags: session, exception, grails, grails-2.3

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot create a session after the response has been committed

Caused by: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages.exceptions.GroovyPagesException: Error processing GroovyPageView: Error executing tag <g:isSelfProfile>: Cannot create a session after the response has been committed
```

After upgrading to Grails 2.3.0 GA, when I try to access the `session` variable (or just call `${session == null}`) in the view, I get an exception if the session was not created before (in the controller).

Comment: probably you should file a jira @ jira.grails.org

Comment: This problem might be fixed since 2.3.3 version. Could anyone confirm? It might be fixed when http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-10780 was fixed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a work around session can be accessed by the request variable without creating a new session. If the session is not created before this will return null.

```
${request.getSession(false)}
```

Also debug mode of the resources plugin i.e. * grails.resources.debug = true * triggers this...

Comment: Works for me by setting a value to session in the controller. Basically, the session should be there before it is accessed.